# Recursive Sequence Tree Problem (Original Research in the Field of Comp. Sci)

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, trees

This question appears also in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17953/recursive-sequence-tree-problem-original-research-in-the-field-of-comp-sci. I was told that cross-posting in this particular situation could be approved, since the question can be viewed from many angles.

I am a researcher in the field of computer science. In my research I have the following problem, which I have been thinking for quite a while now.

I think the problem is best explained through an example, so first assume this kind of a tree structure:

```
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                /                      \
    6, 8, 10, 12                       -4, -4, -4, -4
   /            \                      /             \ 
 16, 20       -4, -4                -8, -8,         0, 0
 /    \       /    \                /     \        /    \
36    -4    -8      0             -16      0      0      0
```

The root of the tree is always some sequence $s = (s_0, ..., s_{N-1})$ where $N = 2^p$ for some $p \in \mathbb{N}, p>2$.  **Please note that I am looking for a general solution to this, not just for sequences of the form $1, 2, ..., 2^p$.** As you can see, the tree is defined in a recursive manner: the left node is given by
 $left(k)=root(k)+root(\frac{N}{2}+k), \quad 0 \leq k \leq \frac{N}{2}$ 
and the right node by
$right(k)=root(k)-root(\frac{N}{2}+k), \quad 0 \leq k \leq \frac{N}{2}$

So, for example, (6 = 1+5, 8 = 2+6, 10 = 3+7, 12 = 4+8) and (-4 = 1-5, -4 = 2-6, -4 = 3-7, -4 = 4-7) would give the second level of the tree.

I am only interested in the lowest level of the tree, i.e., the sequence (36, -4, -8, 0, -16, 0, 0, 0). If I compute the tree recursively, the computational complexity will be $O(N log N)$. That is a little slow for the purpose of the algorithm. Is it possible to calculate the last level in linear time?

If a linear-time algorithm is possible, and you find it, I will add you as an author to the paper the algorithm will appear in. The problem constitutes about 1/10 of the idea/content in the paper.

If a linear-time algorithm is not possible, I will probably need to reconsider other parts of the paper, and leave this out entirely. In such a case I can still acknowledge your efforts in the acknowledgements. (Or, if the solution is a contribution from many people, I could credit the whole math SE community.)

Comment: You might get better answers on the theoretical computer science stackexchange.

Comment: Is double-posting allowed?

Comment: @researcher double-posting is discouraged, but not entirely forbidden.  If you can give good reason on why you've done so, and are very open that you're doing so, it may be received ok.  In general, though, people don't like it.  If you don't get much help here, you can `@` notify (or mention in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)) a [moderator](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) to see if they'll migrate it to the other site for you.

Comment: And an FYI: Be careful with your indexing.  The sequence example you give is **not** an instance of the form of sequence you describe: if you start with $s_0$, then your example sequence ends with $s_{N-1}$, not $s_N$. `:)`

Comment: @anorton: Thank you for the tips. I'll correct the indexing.

Comment: @researcher Yes. I think in this instance it's fine. Just add a link to the other question in this question (and vice-versa). As I said, I think you would be much more helpful answers from trained CS people.

Comment: @Potato: The question now appears on both sites. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the transformation you're asking for is called the Hadamard transform (it essentially works like a discrete Fourier transform). While the "trivial" matrix multiplication takes $O(n^2)$ time, the structure of the matrix allows the computation to be done in $O(n\log n)$ time. However, it's less than like that this can be speeded up further, because that might imply a faster bound for the FFT, which is a major open problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving a name for my problem! After reading about the fast Hadamard algorithm, I guess I should accept the $O(N\log N)$ complexity. Well, I will wait for sometime before accepting your answer, someone could be having his or hers next big idea :-)! I'll definetely do as I promised, and acknowledge you and the math SE community in my forthcoming paper. If it gets accepted, I will post it here.

Answer (score 2):

For the case where $p=3$ and an arbitrary sequence $(s_{1},...,s_{8})$ I constructed the matrix: 
$M=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
 1&-1& 1&-1& 1&-1& 1&-1\\
 1& 1&-1&-1& 1& 1&-1&-1\\
 1&-1&-1& 1& 1&-1&-1& 1\\
 1& 1& 1& 1&-1&-1&-1&-1\\
 1&-1& 1&-1&-1& 1&-1& 1\\
 1& 1&-1&-1&-1&-1& 1& 1\\
 1&-1&-1& 1&-1& 1& 1&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}$ Such that the $i^{th}$ leaf: $L_{i}=\sum^{N}_{j=1}s_{j}M[i,j]$

Stupidly implemented (assuming that $M$ can be built for free!) this would take $O(n^{2})$ time. Of course in computing these sums work can be saved: for example

$L_{1}=\sum^{N}_{i=1}s_{i}$ and 
$L_{\frac{N}{2}+1}=\sum^{\frac{N}{2}}_{i=1}s_{i}-\sum^{N}_{i=\frac{N} {2}+1}s_{i}$

If we compute the two summations in $L_{\frac{N}{2}+1}$ separately we can combine them into two solutions, $L_{1}$ and $L_{\frac{N}{2}+1}$, in constant time. However it is my intuition that a divide-and-conquer strategy modeled on such techniques would fail to improve on your already observed bound of $O(N log(N))$.

I believe that if there is no exploitable structure to the root sequence then the recursive definition you propose is asymptotically optimal. (I'll look into a way to prove this assertion.)

Comment: I like the matrix representation. It has so many repeating (block-) structures, giving me (false, maybe) hope :-)

Answer (score 1):

The $n$th (counting from $1$) term of the lowest level of the tree with root $1..2^p$ is:

$n=1$:   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2^{k-1}(2^k+1) $
which is the $2^k$th triangular number, because when the left branch is followed the sum of all the numbers at each node met remains constant.

$n=2^i+1$:     $\ \ \ \ \  \ \ 2^{k+i-1} $
The first time a right branch is taken, the constant sequence $-2^{n-1}...-2^{n-1}$ occurs, and always following the left branch after that doubles each term.

$0$
for other $n$ because taking the right branch once gives a constant sequence, and a sequence of zeroes the next time the right branch is taken.

Comment: I am looking for a general solution to this, not just for the sequence 1...2^p. I think I state the root of the tree is _some_ sequence, but I guess I should have emphasized this more. Anyway, thank you for your answer! I hope it raises more ideas how to approach the problem. I will edit the question to be more exact.

Comment: @researcher: If you're looking for a general solution, then $O(N\log N)$ is already quite a good computational complexity for such a linear transformation; this is for instance what FFT achieves, which makes use of a strong regularity in the transformation; I'd be surprised if you could do better than that in this case.

Comment: @joriki: I agree with you, this is a complicated problem. I have been working with this for a few months now  without having any big ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment, but it's too big for the comment block.  An interesting note on Kaya's matrix $\mathbf{M}$: I believe that it can be defined recursively for any value of $p$.  (I should note here that this is my belief.  I have yet to prove it...)

That is, let $\mathbf{M}_p$ be the matrix for the value of $p$ (here, let's remove the bound on $p\gt2$).

Let $\mathbf{M}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $\mathbf{M}_n = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{M}_{n-1} & \mathbf{M}_{n-1} \\ \mathbf{M}_{n-1} & -\mathbf{M}_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$.

Ah Ha!  Thanks to some searches based off of Suresh Venkat's answer, I found that this matrix is called the [Walsh Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix).  Multiplying this matrix by a column vector of your first sequence provides a column vector of the bottom sequence.

As a side note, this makes an almost fractal-like pattern when colored. `:)`
[image: A pictured of the colored matrix]
*The above is for $p=4$.*

EDIT: I'm almost sure I've seen a graphic similar to the one above before.  If someone recognizes something similar, that would be great...

Comment: Inspiring answer like Kaya's! Thank you for the nice figure. I will definetely give these kind of approaches more time.